# My wife and I own two cars. Which of us need to be insured on each?

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance

We have two cars; one is a 14 plate Skoda estate lease car. The terms of the lease say I need to have fully-comprehensive insurance.

We also have an old W-reg Renault for my wife, with me as the registered keeper.

We both have separate, fully comprehensive insurance on the Skoda, with clauses stating that we are insured to drive other cars as 3rd-party.

I just got a letter from DVLA saying that the Renault isn't insured.

What insurance setup are we supposed to have in this situation? I'm thinking of transferring the Renault to my wife's name and changing her policy.

Comment: "14 plate" and "DVLA" means it is the UK.

Comment: I'm sure you are not insured while driving an uninsured car.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, clauses letting you drive other cars only apply to cars that you don't own. So I'd check your policies carefully, and then insure the Renault in your wife's name and add her as a named driver to your policy on the Skoda.

Answer (score 6):

[Gov.uk states that](https://www.gov.uk/vehicle-insurance/uninsured-vehicles):

> You must have motor insurance for your **vehicle** if you use it on roads
>   and in public places.

Notice the wording, it's not *you* that must be insured, it's your *"your vehicle"*. That's why you can't tax an uninsured vehicle, etc.

If you read the T&Cs of your other insurance policy (the one for your skoda) it should state something along the lines of: `You will be able to drive another "insured" vehicle 3rd party`. So that other vehicle must also be insured (by someone else for example) for you to be covered.

I'd rectify this ASAP as right now your breaking the law and if your caught you will get a hefty fine if not a ban.